# KL-divergence to compare ML models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

Let us say we have to neural network architectures, A and B and we train $x$ times each of them. Based on the $x$ retrainings, we can calculate $x$ prediction errors for each model, and plot its corresponding distribution. That means, for model A we have an errors density $\mathcal{D}_A$  and for B a density $\mathcal{D}_B$.

Obviously if the mean of the errors of A $\mu_A$ < $\mu_B$ and the standard deviation of the errors of A $\sigma_A < \sigma_B $, I would choose A as my best model. But what if $\mu_A < \mu_B$ but $\sigma_A > \sigma_B$, how do we chose the model.

**My question generally is**: Given two errors densities $\mathcal{D}_A$ and $\mathcal{D}_B$, what metric compares these two to choose a final model. My simple and maybe incorrect approach I thought about is: make a decision about a reference density $\mathcal{D}$(how you like the errors density to be, for example $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$) and use the KL-divergence to compute the "distance" between each of the A and B densities with the reference one, and choose the model with the smaller distance.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested in this question, I finally found out some useful metrics that perform well in comparing distributions (and different from KL-divergence):
Wasserstein metric, Energy metric, Shannon-Entropy metric, Maximum Mean Discrepancy metric. They are metrics in the sense that they satisfy the properties of a mathematical metric(symmetric for example), while the KL-divergence is not symmetric.

Note that the **Shannon-Entropy** metric requires density estimation, while the others require only the collected samples.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me a good idea.

KL divergence would give you a raw distance approximation of your distributions, but not all error values might have the same weight of importance: it highly depends on your error calculation method, and some kind of relative error calculation/weightening could be necessary.

In addition to that, Cross Entropy could also be an interesting option to know the "direction" of the distributions' distance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... What do you mean by 'depends on your error calculation method'. Assume that I am calculating the MAPE (mean average percentage error), how this will affect my logic ..?

Comment: Every method has a different result: MAPE and MSE will not have the same result, neither the same evolution through iterations. As a consequence, the error distribution will not be the same. For instance, the RMSE adds a square to each error that makes high error values more important than MAPE. I recommend using RMSE (good average) or MAE (good use of outliers), rather than MAPE (bad use of high error values & outliers).

Comment: If you consider the answers somewhat usefull, don't hesitate to upvote them as acknowledgment :)

Comment: I see your point ... thanks